Calculated field to sum a specific event
On Looker Studio I'm importing the data that comes from GA4 and I want to do the following:
Given a view, I want to understand which buttons the user has pressed and how may times that was made on a daily basis. I have the following events:

share_button_pressed
save_button_pressed
delete_button_pressed

Since Looker doesn't allow me to simply search for the event name and get its count, I've figured out that I need to add a calculated field using the following:
Name: share button event count
Formula:
CASE 
  WHEN Event name = "share_button_pressed" THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END

And on the field I should use either a COUNT or SUM. Both of them return a random value that doesn't match what it should return.
There's any way around it?

Why don't you use an event_name filter to filter these three events, along with an event_name dimension breakdown and event_count as a metric?

It's an ideia that have worked with graphs and other tables, but I want this information to calculate other indicators and exhibit that into a graph in a way that a drill down metric doesn't allow

I understand. I explained the challenges that this situation faces.

When you use a calculated field as a dimension and select a metric (like event count), Looker Studio should re-aggregate the aggregated metrics, defaulting to the sum. It does not allow for other types of aggregation (such as average or maximum) and displays a flag indicating a data quality issue.
In this case, using the event count metric will yield correct results because it sums records for the defined event name. However, for other metrics like sessions and users, it may retrieve incorrect numbers due to differences in scope and improper aggregation.
A better alternative is to use a window function and query GA4 data in BigQuery, then connect it to Looker Studio.
